# Variable bindings in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

the elisp program

```
(defun test (ee) (symbol-value ee))
(setq e 1.1)
(test 'e)
```

its result is
    1.1

then change the 'ee' in test to 'e',

```
(defun test (e) (symbol-value e))
(setq e 1.1)
(test 'e)
```

its result is
    e

Why are there different results?

Comment: As a take-away, make sure your variable names are unlikely to conflict with other libraries (typically by using a common prefix for all symbols in your library), or with other variables in the same library (by not repeating names like you have in the example above, unless you are sure of what you are doing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formal parameter `e` is bound to the symbol `e`, which is passed as argument.  With lexical binding turned off, when `(symbol-value e)` is evaluated, the value of formal parameter `e` is the symbol `e`, which is returned.  IOW, there is confusion (variable capture) between the symbol passed as argument and the variable bound by the function.

If you use a different symbol, such as `ee`, as argument, then there is no variable capture.
This is a prime example of why dynamic binding can be confusing.

Comment: When set variable lexical-binding to t the second result is 1.1, but when set variable lexical-binding to nil,the first one's result not change

Comment: See above.  If the variable (symbol) that you pass as argument is the same as the variable bound by the function, variable capture occurs.  The value of the argument is the symbol `e` (or `ee`), and the `symbol-value` of the argument `e` is looked up in the dynamic environment, where its `symbol-value` is the symbol `e`.

Comment: If you set `lexical-binding` to `t` then there is no variable capture.